# What are the criteria for subsetting data for testing association?

Tags: correlation, anova, data-transformation, dataset

Working with flight log data set, and would like to test for association between several factors and departure delay in minutes. There are many negative departure delays (often just a few minutes) and 0's for on-time departures. If I eliminate these values and reduce the data set to only delays greater than 15 minutes, would my association testing still be valid?

Comment: What association are you looking at and how do you want to interpret them? For a lot of questions like "what predicts delays?", you do not want to subset.

Comment: @Björn I am building a model so there would be some eventual predicting with coefficients, but mostly it would be ANOVA to look for a statistically significant effect. The problem is that the distribution of delays is counterintiutive. The median is 0 and the mean is around 1.2 if I keep the whole data set. This is because if a plane departs early the departure delay comes out negative. If I modify the data so that all negative delays are 0, the median is still 0 and the mean is only around 5 minutes.

Comment: @Björn So I had subset the data to include only flights that were 10 or more minutes late in departing. But this seems like it would make any results, particularly a predictive model, very limited in their generalizability.